# Scrapy & Selenium: How to call a method in a loop

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I already found similar questions here, but my crawler is still not running.

I am trying to crawl several URLs which I extract from a txt.file. 
This works properly. However, scrapy/selenium opens the browser for each URL one after the other  but does not run the "crawltips"-function. Only for the last URL in my txt.file the code in def `crawltips(self, response):` is executed.

How can I call the "crawltips"-function for each URL in my txt.file?

```
class AlltipsSpider(Spider):
    name = 'allclasses'
    allowed_domains = ['dummy.com']



    def start_requests(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
        with open("urls.txt", "rt") as f:
            start_urls = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]

        for url in start_urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            self.driver.find_element_by_id('currentTab').click()
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_blog-menu"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[3]').click()
            yield Request(self.driver.current_url, callback=self.crawltips)


    def crawltips(self, response):


        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        allposts = sel.xpath('//*[@class="block media _feedPick feed-pick"]')
        for post in allposts:
            username = post.xpath('.//div[@class="col-sm-7 col-lg-6 no-padding"]/a/@title').extract()
            publish_date = post.xpath('.//*[@class="bet-age text-muted"]/text()').extract()


            yield{'Username': username,
                'Publish date': publish_date                
                }
```

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [`scrapy-selenium`](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium). Then you should be able to replace your driver code with `SeleniumRequest`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, WebDriver can focus only on one tab (window) at a time. While running the loop, the last URL is selected and executing the functions there.

For the solution, you have to find the number of tabs based on the URL count and switch back to each URL after completion of the next one.

Eg:

- `browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)` - Move to the new tab and actively work on it.(Use `Keys.SHIFT` for backword tabs )
- `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])` - Using the tab counts(i).

Comment: At the moment it just uses one tab. At first it opens the first URL in one tab and then goes to the second URL and so on....

Comment: In that case, you have to check the availability of response and elements in page using sleep(). make sure that every single case goes through the full code scenarios.

Comment: also does the domain is same for all URLs?

Comment: Jep, it is the same domain for all URLs. That is exactly the problem - how can I make sure that every URL goes through the whole script?

Comment: can you post some URLs so that I can test?

Comment: https://sabobic.blogabet.com
https://dedi22.blogabet.com
https://cheser.blogabet.com/